# Rails 3 Concern Modules for Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

First off, I'm following the practice found here for Rails concerns (great idea!): https://gist.github.com/1014971

I'm getting an error though:

```
undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x5c25ea0>
app/controllers/accessories_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

I **DO** have my /app/models/concerns/ directory loaded in /config/application.rb. So the "concern" modules ARE being loaded. Just wanted to point that out.

Here is my code:

**/app/models/concerns/searchable.rb**

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Add a "search" scope to the models
  def self.search (search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/models/accessory.rb**

```
class Accessory < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Searchable

  ...
end
```

**/app/controllers/accessories_controller.rb**

```
class AccessoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @accessories  = Accessory.search(params[:search])

    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, with a little more toying around I figured out what is wrong!

When you're wanting to directly modify the Model from within the Module (concern), you need to wrap the functionality inside an **included** block.

I've changed my concern module to the following:

```
    module Searchable
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
            # Add a "search" scope to the models
            def self.search (search)
                if search
                    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
                else
                    scoped
                end
            end
        end

    end
```

That is it! Hopefully this will help someone else with the same quesion!

Comment: Good that you figured it out by yourself! A couple more tips: You shouldn't put a space between the method definition and the arguments for the method. It's just not done that way in the Ruby world. Now with regards to the `included` method, what that'll do is evaluate that whole block within the context of the class. If you want to define methods for the class, I would recommend just defining the methods on the module itself, rather than wrapping them inside the included block as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the method name. My own "best practices" sometimes slip in here and there every now and then.

I understand what you're saying about the `included` block. If I were defining a non-self method, I would put it outside the block. Thanks!

Comment: I wish this answer showed up at the top. because this is the correct solution

Answer (score 8):

That's a decent solution but not really the *best* solution.  When you build a module on `ActiveSupport::Concern` you can wrap a module called `ClassMethods` inside your concern and any module that includes your concern will automatically be extended with the `ClassMethods` module.

A better solution, then, would be:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def search(search)
      if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
      else
        scoped
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That (IMO) more clearly expresses your intent: placing a class-level method into the class.

While your approach works, the `included` method is better used when you need to invoke methods on the calling class. For example, you could insist that your `Searchable` objects have a db-backed `name` attribute as shown below.  The `included` method is adding the `presence` validator to the calling class, and the methods you are using to extend the class are clearly separated.

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :validates_presence_of, :name
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def search(search)
      if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
      else
        scoped
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As [AndyV points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973278/356895), the correct solution is this:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def search(search)
      if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
      else
        scoped
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And not defining `self.search` in the `included` block as you are doing in your solution, which is more verbose and less explicit.

But I disagree with AndyV in the usage of `self.included`. If you use `ActiveSupport::Concern`, that's to have the `included` block syntactic sugar, so you should be using it. I only rely on `self.included` when the order of the methods I call or the methods I define matters.